# Laravel notification email facade queue multiple users

Tags: php, laravel, notifications, queue, facade

Here is my code working to send notification email to multiple users

```
$users = User::whereIn('id', $userIds)->get();
\Notification::send($users, new DealPublished($deal));
```

It works but if I want to delay it like that

```
$users = User::whereIn('id', $userIds)->get();

$when = Carbon::now()->addSecond();

\Notification::send($users, new DealPublished($deal))->when($when);
```

Error is

```
FatalThrowableError in DealController.php line 226:
Call to a member function when() on null
```

How can I send notification email to multiple users using queue and Notification Facade ?

Thank's for help

Comment: Try replacing`->when` with `delay` and try again.

Comment: FatalThrowableError in DealController.php line 226:
Call to a member function delay() on null

Comment: If you just want to queue notifications, add `ShouldQueue` interface and `Queuable` trait as mentioned here https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications#queueing-notifications. However it looks you are trying to schedule/delay the notification for a specific time (1 second). Referring to the doc, `delay` only applies to `notify`, which unfortunately, cannot be called with an array, but per user. Maybe a for loop ? Just suggesting.

Comment: Did you include the carbon library like so: use \Carbon\Carbon?

Comment: I'm already using ShouldQueue interface and Queuable trait with Amazon SQS and it's work fine for my others notifications like that : $when = Carbon::now()->addSecond();
    $user->notify((new ForgotPassword($token))->delay($when)); but when I'm using Notification interface, it doesn't work, I don't know why and how to do it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try it like this:

`\Notification::send($users, (new DealPublished($deal))->delay($when));`

Comment: Works for Laravel 6

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try this:

```
$when = Carbon::now()->addSecond(10);

 \Notification::send($users, new DealPublished($deal))->later($when);
```

**OR**

```
\Notification::send($users, new DealPublished($deal))->when($when);
```

Hope this work for you!

Comment: Both does not work for laravel 6, returns `Call to a member function when() on null`

Answer (score 0):

With a foreach loop

```
$when = Carbon::now()->addSecond();
 foreach($users as $user){
     $user->notify((new DealPublished($deal))->delay($when));
 }
```

It works, but if there is 1000+ users to notify, I'm not sure about the execution time :D